# Validação com mais campos Net Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp-net-core, model-validation

Estou precisando fazer validações em um formulário feito em `ASPNet Core MVC`, porém nessa validação eu preciso usar mais de um campo, exemplo abaixo:

***Models:***

```
public class Fornecedor
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DtNascimento { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa{get; set;}
}

public class Empresa
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Uf { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Fornecedor> ListaFornecedor { get; set; }
}
```

Eu preciso criar uma `Validation` na classe Fornecedor que seja feita somente se o atributo UF da empresa for de determinado valor, tentei usa uma `CustomValidation`, mais ou menos assim:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
    object value, 
    ValidationContext validationContext
)
{
    var fornecedor = (Models.Fornecedor) validationContext.ObjectInstance;

    if (fornecedor.Empresa.Uf == "PR")
    {
        if (Utils.GetAge(value) < 18)
        {    
            return 
                new ValidationResult
                ("Para o Paraná, são aceitos apenas fornecedores maiores de idade.");
        }
    }
    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

O objeto Empresa sempre fica nulo, meu `controller` está assim:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(IFormCollection form, Fornecedor fornecedor)
{
    try
    {
        int idEmpresa = int.Parse(form["Empresa"].ToString());
        fornecedor.Empresa = _session.Get<Empresa>(idEmpresa);
        fornecedor.DtHoraCadastro = System.DateTime.Now;
        var ListaEmpresa = _session.Query<Empresa>().ToList();
        ViewBag.ListaEmpresa = ListaEmpresa;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _session.Save(fornecedor);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View();
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Já pesquisei vários lugares mas todos os exemplos são feitos usados vários atributos dentro da mesma classe e não usando atributos dentro de um objeto dentro da classe principal.

Comment: Como está o input dos campos referente a Empresa na sua View?

Comment: O problema ai é na sua View? como está configurado a sua View? poste o exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que sua CustomValidation ocorre quando o objeto é mapeado pela a aplicação e passado para Action e neste momento Empresa é nulo. Neste seu caso, é melhor utilizar [Action Filters](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Crie um Filter para a sua Action:

```
    namespace ActionFilters.Filters
{
    public class ActionFilterExample : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            // our code before action executes
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // our code after action executes
        }
    }
}
```

Faça a injeção de denpendência:

```
services.AddScoped<ActionFilterExample>();
```

E depois faça sua implementação de acordo com o que precisar:

```
namespace ActionFilters.Filters
    {
        public class ActionFilterExample : IActionFilter
        {
            private readonly IEmpresaService _service;

            public ActionFilterExample(IEmpresaService empresaSservice)
            {
                _service = empresaSservice;
            }

            public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
            {
                var fornecedor = context.ActionArguments.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Value is Fornecedor) is Fornecedor;
                if(fornecedor != null)
                {
                    fornecedor.Empresa = _service.GetById(idEmpresa); //Utilize o seu serviço para buscar a empresa
                    if (fornecedor.Empresa.Uf == "PR")
                    {
                        if (Utils.GetAge(value) < 18)
                        {

                            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Para o Paraná, são aceitos apenas fornecedores maiores de idade.");
                            return;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
            {
                // our code after action executes
            }
        }
    }
```